# PHP trader extension candle recognition errors

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know if anyone has run into this or have had a similar problem with the PHP trader extension:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.trader.php

Any help would be really appreciated, here's what I have done:

1. "Installed" the DLL and updated my php.ini to load the extension.
2. I have a php page with "print_r(get_extension_funcs("trader"));" and produced an array with all the trader functions, so I assume it is installed ok.
3. I have run various moving average/adx/cci etc functions and I get an array of results.

BUT whenever I try to run ANY of the candle recognition functions I get a response of "False", which looking at the link below means the function has not run correctly. I'm expecting an Array of 6 results not a Boolean of "False".

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trader-cdldoji.php

```
$open = [112.818, 112.226, 111.725, 112.144, 112.463, 112.205]; 
$high = [113.21,113.257,112.476,112.53,112.554,112.716];  
$low = [112.253,112.219,111.497,111.474,111.653,112.134];
$close = [112.339,112.804,112.234,111.716,111.993,112.483];
$test1 = trader_cdldoji($open, $high, $low, $close);
var_dump($test1);
```

I'm really struggling with this as the code above is so simple I can't believe it doesn't work, I have also tried the following:

```
$open = [112.818, 112.226, 111.725, 112.144, 112.463, 112.205]; 
$high = [113.21,113.257,112.476,112.53,112.554,112.716];  
$low = [112.253,112.219,111.497,111.474,111.653,112.134];
$close = [112.339,112.804,112.234,111.716,111.993,112.483];
$test1 = array(trader_cdldoji($open, $high, $low, $close));
var_dump($test1);
```

I'm really hoping I've done something really stupid that I just can't see after a couple of hours of hair pulling! Any help much appreciated, thanks everyone,

George

Comment: Have you tried it with more values? The only way I manage to get a non-`false` result from `trader_cdldoji()` is by using arrays with 11 or more values. Since I have no idea what that function does or what it's used for, I'm not sure how much help that is.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, just copied and pasted from arrays with a length of six to arrays with a length of twelve and I now get:

    array (size=2)
      10 => float 0
      11 => float 0

So problem solved, hope this helps other people in my positian. Thanks to rickdenhaan, really appreciate it, saved me a sleepless night :)

Comment: By the way if you want to respond, I'll tag you as the accepted answer to the problem, as you totally nailed it, thanks. From now on I'll never choose an even number for a test. Prime time! Maybe 13 :) Thanks again, I was going slowly mad... :)

Comment: No problem, I added it as an answer. What does this function actually *do*?

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted this as the answer, saved me loads of time doing the same thing over and over. If you're interested the candle recognition of the trader extension just search for specific OHLC patterns. You can learn more about the various patterns here:

http://www.candlescanner.com/patterns-dictionary/

Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what that function does (the documentation for the `trader` extension is hopelessly lacking), but it appears that 6 values is not enough. I ran some tests and only got it to give me an actual result if the arrays contain 11 or more values.